# Can't display Google Map view on application

Tags: android, google-maps

First, you have to know that English is not my mother tongue, so I apologize if it's bad.

I am new in android development, and I have to continue an Android application started by a former fellow worker a few month ago (he's now gone).

In this application, we have a list of users, with their adresses, and I have to display a Google Map view by clicking on theses adresses. Even if Google Map is lunched, an exception is raised.

Here is the code :

```
public class GMapsViewCopy extends MapActivity
{

private static final int DIALOG_ERREUR = 100;

    private MapView mapView;
    private MapController mc;
    private GeoPoint location;

    /**
     * Creation de l'activity
     */
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.gmapsview);
        setTitle("Google Maps");

        mapView = (MapView) this.findViewById(R.id.GMaps);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        String adresse = (String) this.getIntent().getStringExtra("adresse");
        Log.i("", "Adresse : " + adresse);
        location = this.getCoord(adresse);

        if (location != null)
        {
            Log.i("", "location != null");
            MonOverlay marker = new MonOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker));
            marker.addPoint(location);
            mapView.getOverlays().add(marker);

            this.mc = this.mapView.getController();
            this.mc.setCenter(this.location);
            this.mc.setZoom(16);
        } else
            showDialog(DIALOG_ERREUR);
    }

    /**
     * Permet de récuperer les coordonnées géographique du patient à partir de
     * son adresse
     * 
     * @param adresse
     * @return GeoPoint
     */
    private GeoPoint getCoord(String adresse)
    {
        GeoPoint point = null;
        Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try
        {
            List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(adresse, 5);
            /*
             * for(int i=0; i<addresses.size(); i++) { Log.i("",
             * "Adresse["+i+"] : "+addresses.get(i)); }
             */
            if (addresses.size() > 0)
            {
                point = new GeoPoint(
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                        (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.i("", "exception : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return point;
    }

    public GeoPoint getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(GeoPoint location)
    {
        this.location = location;
        this.mc.setCenter(this.location);
        this.mapView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    public class MonOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem>
    {
        List<GeoPoint> points = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

        public MonOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker)
        {
            super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i)
        {
            GeoPoint point = points.get(i);
            return new OverlayItem(point, "titre", "description");
        }

        @Override
        public int size()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return points.size();
        }

        public void addPoint(GeoPoint point)
        {
            this.points.add(point);
            populate();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Permet de créer des boites de dialog
     */
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
        case DIALOG_ERREUR:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(GMapsViewCopy.this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details)
                    .setTitle("Nous n'avons pas pu trouver l'adresse indiquée.")
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                    {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton)
                        {
                            finish();
                        }
                    }).create();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Fermeture de l'activity
     */
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

My manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cba.myandroid"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<activity 
            android:name=".GMapsView"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

And my gmapview.xml (res/layout) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView 
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:apiKey="myKey"
        />

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, what exactly is your exception ?
Second, if you test on the debugger, be sure that you're using an AVD that is based on Google API's. AVD's based on standard platform can not run Google maps view. To do so, you need to download extra package with the ADT interface.
Third, you need to fill your api key  android:apiKey in your gmapview.xml. You'll find more info about this point here : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Comment: hank you for your answer.

I am talking about this function :  protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)

When I clic on an adress, this error dialog appears.

And about my API key, I put "myKey" voluntarily (You understand I don't want to show my key to everyone ^^)

Comment: I was asking for the exception you meet, from the logcat window for isntance. Are you testing on a device or on the emulator ? If it's the emulator, are you using google API's ?

Comment: I am testing on real device (Galaxy S & SII and HTC desire)

Comment: Once again, what is the exact exception you have ?

Comment: It's okay , I solved my problem. Thank you for your answers Raphael